# How to continuesly sync the "changed" document from ML DB to a diskfolder with NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

With the marklogic nifi connector, I could bring the documents from ML DB to a disk folder with Nifi. The key is with **QueryMarkLogic Processor**.

I need to set up a workflow to continuously monitor ML DB content db to bring in any "changed" documents into a disk folder.

How to do that?

I am thinking to use a "sync flag" collection to tag on documents that have been "changed" in ML. (That means document changes have to be made via a custom XQuery function internally in ML). Then run a server transform script to clear that collection in QueryMarkLogic Processor. That is to ensure it will put the file once only.

However, how to to make the **QueryMarkLogic Processor** continuously run that query?
It seems that I will have to stop the query processor and start again to monitor that "sync flag" collection again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the schedule tab of the processor.

Run Schedule - 10 sec
Concurrent Tasks - 1

This is essentially saying 10 seconds after the previous task has completed.